# How can I know the max possible transmit power of my wireless card?

Tags: wifi, hardware

Is there any way for me to tell the maximum possible power of my wireless card from within Linux?

Or do I need to find the product number of the card, and search for specifications like that online?

Comment: You can find out the maximum broadcast power of the card with `iw`. The exact command evades me at the moment...

Answer (score 4):

`iw list` will also tell you the allowed max power output by frequency. The number in brackets is the max power. I'm not aware of any other way of finding the *absolute* maximum of the device.

```
            Frequencies:
                    * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
iwlist <interface> txpower
```

tells you that information, if device provides it.

Eg;

```
# iwlist eth0 txpower
eth0      8 available transmit-powers :
          5 dBm         (3 mW)
          7 dBm         (5 mW)
          9 dBm         (7 mW)
          11 dBm        (12 mW)
          13 dBm        (19 mW)
          15 dBm        (31 mW)
          17 dBm        (50 mW)
          19 dBm        (79 mW)
          Current Tx-Power=13 dBm       (19 mW)
```

Comment: It would be useful to provide sample output showing usage.

Comment: Keep in mind that `iwlist` is being deprecated in favour of `iw`

Comment: @Lawrence Do you know the equivalent `iw` command that produces the same type of output?

Answer (score 1):

It is related to which country you live and have a look at [WIFI power by country](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/wcs/3-2/configuration/guide/wcscfg32/wcscod.html)

Some software allow you to go higher than maximum allowed power but that is illegal.

Comment: It's exactly that "higher than maximum allowed" value I'm trying to find, I want to know what the card is capable of. In addition, some cards may have max power values lower than the maximum allowed by the country, so really, the "legal maximum" is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Generally the card will not let you go over the legal maximum.

Comment: Find technical spec document for your card, that would be your best shot.

Answer (score 0):

If iwlist is not available your system (like OpenWrt) may provide iwinfo:

```
# iwinfo phy0 txpower
   0 dBm (   1 mW)
   1 dBm (   1 mW)
   2 dBm (   1 mW)
   3 dBm (   1 mW)
...
   8 dBm (   6 mW)
   9 dBm (   7 mW)
  10 dBm (  10 mW)
* 11 dBm (  12 mW)
  12 dBm (  15 mW)
...
  18 dBm (  63 mW)
  19 dBm (  79 mW)
  20 dBm ( 100 mW)
```

I shorted the output for this CPE210.